# Handling chunked request in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, http, nginx, sinatra, passenger

In Sinatra I have a route setup similar to the following:

```
put '/test' do
  begin
    logger.info 'In put begin block'

    write_to_file(request.body.read)

    [200, '']
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    [500, 'some error']
  end
end

def write_to_file(data)
  logger.info "writing data with size #{data.size}"
  # Code to save file...
end
```

When I send data that is < ~500 MBytes it everything seems to work correctly but when I attempt to send data that is >= 500 MBytes I get some weird log output and then the client eventually errors out with the following error: Excon::Errors::SocketError: EOFError (EOFError)

The logs from the server (Sinatra) look like the following:

For data < 500 MBytes:

```
I, [2013-01-07T21:33:59.386768 #17380]  INFO -- : In put begin block
I, [2013-01-07T21:34:01.279922 #17380]  INFO -- : writing data with size 209715200
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Jan/2013 21:34:22] "PUT /test " 200 - 22.7917
```

For data > 500 MBytes:

```
I, [2013-01-07T21:47:37.434022 #17386]  INFO -- : In put begin block
I, [2013-01-07T21:47:41.152932 #17386]  INFO -- : writing data with size 524288000
I, [2013-01-07T21:48:16.093683 #17380]  INFO -- : In put begin block
I, [2013-01-07T21:48:20.300391 #17380]  INFO -- : writing data with size 524288000
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Jan/2013 21:48:39] "PUT /test " 200 - 62.4515
I, [2013-01-07T21:48:54.718971 #17386]  INFO -- : In put begin block
I, [2013-01-07T21:49:00.381725 #17386]  INFO -- : writing data with size 524288000
I, [2013-01-07T21:49:33.980043 #17267]  INFO -- : In put begin block
I, [2013-01-07T21:49:41.990671 #17267]  INFO -- : writing data with size 524288000
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Jan/2013 21:50:06] "PUT /test " 200 - 110.2076
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Jan/2013 21:51:22] "PUT /test " 200 - 108.5339
```

Not entirely sure whats going on here so I guess my question is two fold, A. What is fundamentally different between these two cases that would cause them to behave this way? B. Is there a better way to handle data to mitigate against this?

Comment: what web-server did you use? Webrick? Thin?

Comment: did you check here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sinatrarb/Ve_y3-Vx1w8

Comment: I am currently using passenger with apache

Comment: did you try to adjust LimitRequestBody Directive ?

Comment: Just tried that and I get the same outcome.

Comment: just another wild guess but did you try adjust KeepAliveTimeout directive ?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but I'm still getting the same behavior. I'm guessing it has something to do with Rack and how it's choosing to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be with apache/passenger. Running the server with WEBrick alleviated the issue.